# How to split a levy

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm playing the Game of Thrones conversion mod and because of the way the provinces are set up, it's very easy to have individual levies larger than my entire fleet.  I know you can create multiple groups of levies by assigning the levies of each barony to a different group, but is it possible to split the levy of a single barony?

i.e.: Playing as a Greyjoy count, one of my castles can produce a levy of 2,000 troops on its own while I can only raise 16 ships total.  Since I can't find a way to split them, there's no way to get those men to the mainland, even with multiple trips.  Only being able to use the forces of my vassals, who have smaller levies or will not let me levy their entire force, dramatically reduces my military power.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that.  Try getting another county with more ships, or improving your relations with the (one?) county that can produce ships, so they'll give you more ships when you ask them.

Comment: problem is, in the Game of Thrones mod, they made it difficult to use ships for armies on purpose. In the lore, otherwise unimportant realms are crucial because they have lots of ships, while most other realms need to move their troops by land.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot split an individual unit (i.e. a levy from a single source).  The manual doesn't come out and say it, but [this dev diary](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/content.php?594-Crusader-Kings-II-Dev-Diary-10-Combat) talks about it.

One way to get a smaller individual unit would be to send the troops to non-friendly lands (i.e. not yours or a vassel's) and then dismiss them.  But that might not be possible since you probably don't have any non-friendly territory to which you can march the troops.

@Paul Marshall's idea of getting more ships is also good one.  Maybe there are mercenaries navies you can hire to transport your large levy?